# Stash Channel Entries Loop -> Replacing a part of Tag Pair field name?

Tags: ee2, stash, parse-order

Stash 2.6.7
EE 2.10.1

I've been stumped on this one for over 8 hours and feel like I'm overlooking something so simple.  I've reviewed the Low parse order guide but still can't get it to work.  I've tried different routes with using get_list, setting exp:stash:set to snippet type, etc.

```
{!-- LIMIT & GRAB ONLY FIRST CATEGORY NAME OF ENTRY (Entry can have multiple categories) --}
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" dynamic="no" limit="6" disable="member_data|pagination"}
    {exp:stash:set name="entry_{entry_id}_category" trim="yes" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
            {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" depth="1" limit="1" style="linear"}
                {cat_url_title}
            {/exp:gwcode_categories}
    {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- DROP IN STASH VARIABLE FOR FLEXIBLE TAG PAIR --}
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" dynamic="no" limit="6" disable="member_data|pagination" parse="inward"}

            {{stash:entry_{entry_id}_category}_resource_images}
            <div class="thumb">
                <a href="#"><img src="{image:url:small}" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            {/{stash:entry_{entry_id}_category}_resource_images}

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}


--------


{!-- WORKS IF I SIMPLY DROP IN SEGMENT_2 (which is "print" category) --}
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" dynamic="no" limit="6" disable="member_data|pagination" parse="inward"}

            {{segment_2}_resource_images}
            <div class="thumb">
                <a href="#"><img src="{image:url:small}" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            {/{segment_2}_resource_images}

{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

As you see in the third block above, replacing the Stash variable with segment_2 which translates to "print" works and pulls in the image.  So it's definitely a parse order issue.  How can I get Stash to parse '{stash:entry_{entry_id}_category}' first before parsing the outer tag pair?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stash parses any known `{stash:variable}` style markers at the beginning of each pass of the tagdata it wraps (working from the top layers of tags inwards). However `{stash:entry_{entry_id}_category}` does not resolve to a known stash variable until *after* `{entry_id}` has been parsed by the channel entries tag. By which point the channel entries tag has completed parsing and it's too late.

I would instead use nested stash lists:

```
{!-- set a list of entries, the first assinged category and all possible images fields --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="entries" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="resources" dynamic="no" limit="6" disable="member_data|pagination"}

        {!-- capture all the single value fields you need here --}
        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}

        {!-- capture the category for the entry --}
        {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" depth="1" limit="1" style="linear"}
            {stash:cat_url_title}{cat_url_title}{/stash:cat_url_title}
        {/exp:gwcode_categories}

        {!-- capture images for every possible category here, assuming each is a custom field --}
        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="category_print" context="{entry_id}"}
            {print_resource_images}
                {stash:url}{image:url:small}{/stash:url}
            {/print_resource_images}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="category_another" context="{entry_id}"}
            {another_resource_images}
                {stash:url}{image:url:small}{/stash:url}
            {/another_resource_images}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

        {!-- ...etc... --}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}


{exp:stash:get_list name="entries"}

    <h1>{title}</h1>

    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="category_{cat_url_title}" context="{entry_id}" prefix="image"}
    <div class="thumb">
        <a href="#"><img src="{image:url}" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately it is outputting all the images collected by the "categories" and "tag_pairs" Stashes in one go, instead of only outputting one image per entry.  Is there a way to Stash the category_url_title found per entry?

*

Comment: I updated the code, let me know how you get on.

Comment: Perfecto!  Thanks so much for taking time out of your day to help me solve this, Mark!  Now I can get rid of my {embed} and use this as a solution and a case for future Stash uses.